# Font Scale according to parent div

Tags: css, reactjs

I am having a `h3`, which may have long or sometimes short text. I have manually set the `font-size` of the `h3` to `3rem`. But when it is a long text, the text starts to overflow the parent div. When it is a short text, it appears to be small (font-size). How can I make the `h3`'s `font-size` to automatically scale according to the parent div? **Note** that the parent div has a fixed height and width and has nothing to do with the screen size.

```
<div id="book_div">
  <div className="book-div_container">
    <p className="book-div_author">{author}</p>
    <div className="book_div_data">
      {series && <h2 className="book_div_series">{series}</h2>}
      <h3 id="bookdivtitle" className="book_div_title">
        {title}
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

 #book_div {
  height: 18.875rem;
  width: 12.25rem;
  background-color: #857073;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Noto Sans JP", sans-serif;
  padding: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px grey;
}

.book-div_container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.book-div_author {
  font-size: 100%;
}

.book_div_data {
  padding-top: 3rem;
}
.book_div_series {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.book_div_title {
  text-align: center;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

**Edit:**
CodeSandbox link is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-bash-j9rys?file=/src/App.js).

Any help is greatly appreciated ! 
Thanks!

Comment: `em` is used for scaling according to parent size & `rem` is used for scaling according to root element, i.e, `html`

Comment: Thanks! I changed it into `3em`. But it overflows the parent `div` if it is a large text

Comment: Make a JSFiddle with some text that shows what happens :)

Comment: Thanks! Here it is: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-bash-j9rys?file=/src/App.js

Comment: What do you want to happen? If you want it to stop overflowing the boundary, then use overflow property. If you want it to follow parent's `font-size` then put `font-size` on the `div` of `h3` in `px`. You can't scale `h3` automatically on parent's text side like if you want long text to be smaller in size & small text to be bigger in size. Maybe you can in JS but not CSS I think :)

Comment: Thanks! If I can go with js how can I continue ?

Comment: Check if the text is long, then assign it a small font-size (16px). If it is short, then assign it a large font-size (20px) & this requires lots of trial & error but I don't understand why would you want to do such thing but that's the solution. You can also check out https://github.com/rikschennink/fitty

Comment: Because, sometimes the `title` will be short, so I want the text to fit the `div`. Otherwise, if the text is long, I want the `title`'s font-size to reduce....:)